# Reducing project dependencies

Tags: c#, mvvm

I am not really satisfied with my project setup, so I hope you can give me some tips to improve it.

I have the following projects in my Blank Solution right now:

```
* Model (Portable Class Library)
* ViewModel (Portable Class Library)
* DataAccess (Class Library) because of using Entity Framework 6
* App.WPF (WPF-Application for Desktop)
```

In my DataAcces project I have an interface 'IRepository' and an implementation 'EFRepo' which implements 'IRepository'. My 'PersonViewModel'-class in ViewModel project gets a DataAccess via constructor dependency injection:

```
public  PersonViewModel(IRepository dal){...}
```

If I want to instantiate the DataContext in my 'App.WPF' project:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new PersonViewModel();
}
```

my MainWindow in the 'App.WPF' needs to reference these projects:

```
* Model
* ViewModel
* DataAccess
```

I think this is to much. The View (App.WPF) should only know the ViewModel, right? How can I achieve this?

I have tried to create a 'Shared Project' called Interfaces and another Class Library called 'Implementation' where I have put the `EFRepo` implementation of `IRepository`. But then I have to make my `DataContext` from the `DataAccess` project public and the class library 'Implementation' have to reference to `Entity.dll`, too...

So all in all I am confused how to handle it in an acceptable way. I want to use the ViewModel as Desktop (WPF), Silverlight and Windows Phone app for education purpose, that's why I try to keep everything independent.

I use Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

Comment: it's probably the usual problem with EF (it leaks) - you should not need the DataAccess part down there - put the interfaces besides the models and you can probably put the viewmodels to the UI (WPF app) so DA->Model->WPF - there is a way to separate the EF-models from the contexts but I really dislike it so much that I write models that I translate in the implementation of the repository-patterns instead

Comment: Hey Carsten, if I put my ViewModels in the App.WPF would work, but what do I have to do if I need the viewModels in a silverlight or windows phone app?

Comment: if you choose to to so later you can refactor them out again I guess ... sorry I missed the part, but it's not that important - refactor them out in their own project if you like

Comment: As you have said: 'refactor them out in their own project': So if I know I need them for seperate projects and could write them into my own project called 'ViewModels' as I have done... Or do I misundertand you?

Comment: so what exactly is your question? Or do you just want opinions (sadly this is the wrong place to ask for those)